# Prevent any exceptions to be displayed to the user?

Tags: java, jsf, exception, jakarta-ee

How can I prevent any exceptions occurring to be displayed to the user?
I could instead imagine to just redirect the user to a specific page if *any* error occures.

Especially I want to prevent HTTP Status 500 view exceptions like this:

```
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: /index.xhtmlNo saved view state could be found for the view identifier: /index.xhtml
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute(RestoreViewExecutor.java:132)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:170)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:197)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not define custom error pages in your `web.xml`? You can specify HTTP error codes as in:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/myerror.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

...or Java exception classes:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/myerror.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

This solution has the advantage of not requiring any extra implementation - except for the error page itself.

Answer (score 4):

Basically you can add an Exception Handler to the MyFaces configuration.

You need to provide a factory method and then an implementation.  You also need to set up an error page re-direct.

https://cwiki.apache.org/MYFACES/handling-server-errors.html

Answer (score 0):

In the catch block **remove** the `printStackTrace()` method...and **write the Redirection** code

**Eg:**

```
try{

        // Your code

     }catch(Exception ex){

       // Redirection Code

     }
```

Comment: This is a bad practice of handling exceptions in JSF. Please don't learn JSF based on roseindia.net tutorials or something.

Answer (score -3):

agree with @Kumar Vivek Mitra, but i think you can add the redirect in the finally block

```
 try{

    // Your code

 }catch(Exception ex){

   // syserr

 }finally{
      //redirect
 }
```

Comment: That would always redirect; definitely not what OP is looking for.